# How to alleviate "variable lengths differ" error in linear model function

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm trying to create a script that outputs a table of adjusted r-squared values for every combination of eight input variables of a multiple linear regression model.

The way I attempted this was by creating every combination of column names in my data frame and concatenating these strings with "+" signs, and storing each of these in a vector. Then, I looped through each of these and retrieved the adjusted r-squared value and stored them in a new vector. The dataframe I used is called WasteData.

```
my.vars <- matrix(0, ncol=8, nrow=)
my.vars <- t(matrix(noquote(colnames(WasteData[2:9]))))
sum.vars <- rep("", 255)
r.2 <- rep(0, 255)
comb.mat <- matrix(numeric(0), nrow=8, ncol=0)

for ( i in 1:8 ) { 

  t.mat <- combn(my.vars, m=i)

  comb.mat <- cbind(comb.mat, rbind(t.mat, matrix("", ncol=dim(t.mat)[2] , nrow=8-i)))
}

for ( j in 1:dim(comb.mat)[2] ) {
    lim = 0  
    for (i in 1:8) {
      if(comb.mat[i,j] == "") {
        lim = i-1
        break;
      }
    }
    temp = comb.mat[1:lim,j]
    sum.vars[j] = paste(temp, collapse = " + ")
    sum.vars[dim(comb.mat)[2]] = "INDUS + METAL + WHOLE + RETAIL + REST + FINAN + MISC + HOME" #this line shows each of the eight variables

    r.2[j] = summary(lm(WASTE ~ noquote(sum.vars[j]), WasteData))$adj.r.squared
 }
```

The sum.vars vector compiles correctly giving me every correct argument to the right of the "~" in the linear model, but once I run a lm, i get the following error:

Error in model.frame.default(formula = WASTE ~ noquote(sum.vars[j]), data = WasteData,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'noquote(sum.vars[j])')

Comment: `noquote` doesn't do what you think it does. There are other ways to do this sort of thing, but probably the simplest for you is to build the _entire_ formula, including `WASTE`, as a character string using `paste`. So you should be passing character formulas like `"WASTE ~ VAR1 + VAR2"` to the formula argument in `lm`.

Comment: @joran thank you this worked out, although I don't get why

Comment: The way `lm` works is that you give it a data frame `data = WasteData` and then it looks for columns in that data frame with the same names as the names in your formula. There is special "magic" that allows the formula to be specified unquotes, e.g. `WASTE ~ INDUS + METAL`. It takes the literal name `WASTE` and looks for a column like that. If you mix that with things like `sum.vars[j]` that merely _refer_ to a variable, R doesn't know you've switched systems and looks for a variable literally called `sum.vars[j]` in your data frame.

Comment: Passing the formula as a single character allows `lm` to convert it an actual unquoted formula via `as.formula` or something and then proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an *apply* family approach to build and iterate through character vector of linear formulas without the bookkeeping of initializing a matrix and assigning iteratively in `for` loop. Specifically, to resolve your two actions:

> 1. create every combination of column names in my data frame and concatenating these strings with "+" signs, and storing each of these in a vector.
> 2. loop through each of these and retrieved the adjusted r-squared value and stored them in a new vector.

**`lapply` + `combn`** and **`rapply`**

```
expvar_list <- lapply(seq_along(names(WasteData)[-1]), function(x) 
                      combn(names(WasteData)[-1], x, simplify=FALSE))

formulas_vec <- rapply(expvar_list, function(x) paste("WASTE ~", paste(x, collapse=" + ")))
formulas_vec
```

**`sapply` + `as.formula`**

```
# NAMED VECTOR OF adj-R
r_square_vec <- sapply(formulas_vec, function(f) 
                       summary(lm(as.formula(f), WasteData))$adj.r.squared)

# ONE-COLUMN MATRIX WITH ROW NAMES OF adj-R    
r_square_mat <- as.matrix(r_square_vec)
```

[Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/GFSV16248)